# ListView with selector isn't working in Froyo

Tags: listview, colors, selector, android-2.2-froyo

I have this:

row_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/yellow" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

album_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
```

AlbumCursorAdapter.java

```
public class AlbumCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
...
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.album_item, parent, false);
...
}
```

Why is working in android 4.0 and isn't working in Froyo?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

android:state_activated was introduced in android 3.0 (API 11) [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_activated)